# Videos not displaying properly when loading more than one background video on the same page

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a cover section on my website where as the user scrolls through the page, the video background fades between one of four different clips. I have the code for the cover itself working, and the code that fades between the video works, but for some reason, only one of the four videos displays on the page. I checked the code for each one individually and confirmed that the code itself is correct (video links are good), but If I have more than one, only the first one shows up. Oddly enough, if I have two videos and I reverse the order of the video tags, sometimes both will show. Is this a limitation of the browser or is there a setting somewhere I'm missing?

I created a code example that illustrates the problem using a chunk from the code on the page. I added colored borders for each of the four video clips so you can see which is which. In it's current state, only the first video shows. The other three clips stay black as they are faded in and out.

```js
        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
            let percentScrolled = getPercentScrolled('#container_top', '#sticky_top');
            if (percentScrolled <= 25) {
                scrollFadeElement("#glass_city_background_vid1", percentScrolled, 20, 25, 1, 0);
                scrollFadeElement("#glass_city_background_vid2", percentScrolled, 20, 25, 0, 1);
                scrollFadeElement("#glass_city_background_vid3", percentScrolled, 0, 25, 0, 0);
                scrollFadeElement("#glass_city_background_vid4", percentScrolled, 0, 25, 0, 0);
            } else if (percentScrolled > 25 && percentScrolled <= 50) {
                scrollFadeElement("#glass_city_background_vid1", percentScrolled, 25, 50, 0, 0);
                scrollFadeElement("#glass_city_background_vid2", percentScrolled, 45, 50, 1, 0);
                scrollFadeElement("#glass_city_background_vid3", percentScrolled, 45, 50, 0, 1);
                scrollFadeElement("#glass_city_background_vid4", percentScrolled, 25, 50, 0, 0);
            } else if (percentScrolled > 50 && percentScrolled <= 75) {
                scrollFadeElement("#glass_city_background_vid1", percentScrolled, 50, 75, 0, 0);
                scrollFadeElement("#glass_city_background_vid2", percentScrolled, 50, 75, 0, 0);
                scrollFadeElement("#glass_city_background_vid3", percentScrolled, 70, 75, 1, 0);
                scrollFadeElement("#glass_city_background_vid4", percentScrolled, 70, 75, 0, 1);
            } else {
                scrollFadeElement("#glass_city_background_vid1", percentScrolled, 75, 100, 0, 0);
                scrollFadeElement("#glass_city_background_vid2", percentScrolled, 75, 100, 0, 0);
                scrollFadeElement("#glass_city_background_vid3", percentScrolled, 75, 100, 0, 0);
                scrollFadeElement("#glass_city_background_vid4", percentScrolled, 95, 100, 1, 0);
            }
        });

        /**
        * Returns the percentage (0 to 100) of the way scrolled through a sticky container
        * @param {*} stickyContainer    CSS selector to get the parent container holding container holding the sticky element
        * @param {*} stickyElement      CSS selector to get the sticky element
        * @returns 
        */
        function getPercentScrolled(stickyContainer, stickyElement) {
            container = document.querySelector(stickyContainer).getBoundingClientRect();
            stickyElement = document.querySelector(stickyElement).getBoundingClientRect();

            let scrollPosition = -container.top; // Sticky height >= viewport height
            let scrollHeight = container.height - stickyElement.height;

            let percentScrolled = (scrollPosition / scrollHeight) * 100;
            if (percentScrolled > 100) percentScrolled = 100;
            else if (percentScrolled < 0) percentScrolled = 0;

            //console.log('stickyElement.heightt: ', stickyElement.height);
            //console.log('scrollPosition: ', scrollPosition);
            //console.log('scrollHeight: ', scrollHeight);
            //console.log('percentScrolled: ', percentScrolled);

            return percentScrolled;
        }

        /**
        * Applies a fade effect to the specified element
        * @param {*} fadeElement       Element to apply the fade effect to
        * @param {*} percentScrolled   Current scroll percentage value to trigger the animation
        * @param {*} startPercent      Starting scroll percentage value to trigger the animation
        * @param {*} endPercent        Ending scroll percentage value to trigger the animation
        * @param {*} startFadeAmount   Start fade value (0-1)
        * @param {*} endFadeAmount     End fade value (0-1)
        * @param {*} easingCurve       (Optional) - Characteristic easing curve to use when animating (see easingFunction documentation for details)
        *                              Defaults to linear if no curve type is specified
        */
        function scrollFadeElement(fadeElement, percentScrolled, startPercent, endPercent, startFadeAmount, endFadeAmount, easingCurve) {
            // Get references to the HTML elements to work with
            fadeElement = document.querySelector(fadeElement);

            // Calculate and apply the amount to fade the element
            if (easingCurve === undefined)
                fadeElement.style.opacity = incrementOverRange(percentScrolled, startPercent, endPercent, startFadeAmount, endFadeAmount);
            else
                fadeElement.style.opacity = incrementOverRange(easingFunction(percentScrolled, startPercent, endPercent, easingCurve), percentScrolled, startPercent, endPercent, startFadeAmount, endFadeAmount);
        }

        /**
        * Returns a value within a custom range based on the input percent scrolled value
        * @param {*} percentValue       Value to be transformed from the start/end percent range to the min/max value range
        * @param {*} startPercent      Starting percentage value to begin incrementing the value range
        * @param {*} endPercent        Ending percentage value to end incrementing the value range
        * @param {*} minValue          Starting value of the value range
        * @param {*} maxValue          Ending value of the value range
        * @returns                     The corresponding value within the value range
        */
        function incrementOverRange(percentValue, startPercent, endPercent, minValue, maxValue) {
            // Limit input range to start/end Percent range
            if (percentValue < startPercent)
                percentValue = startPercent;
            else if (percentValue > endPercent)
                percentValue = endPercent;

            // NOTE: Formula borrowed from Arduino map() function
            return ((percentValue - startPercent) * (maxValue - minValue) / (endPercent - startPercent) + minValue);
        }
```

```css
        /* CSS for sticky cover */
        .sticky_cover {
            position: sticky;
            display: block;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        /* NOTE: Must specify height of container locally */
        .sticky_cover_container {
            position: relative;
            width: 100vw;
            left: 50% !important;
            transform: translateX(-50%) !important;
            overflow: visible !important;
        }

        #container_top {
            height: 800vh;
        }

        #glass_city_background_vid1 {
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 10px;
            border-color: red;
        }

        #glass_city_background_vid2 {
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 10px;
            border-color: green;
        }

        #glass_city_background_vid3 {
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 10px;
            border-color: blue;
        }

        #glass_city_background_vid4 {
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 10px;
            border-color: yellow;
        }
```

```html
    <div id="container_top" class="sticky_cover_container">
        <div id="sticky_top" class="sticky_cover" style="background: black">
            <!-- Video Background 1 -->
            <video autoplay muted loop id="glass_city_background_vid1" style="opacity: 1" class="cover_img">
                <source src="https://www.midstory.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/paragraph1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <!-- Video Background 2 -->
            <video autoplay muted loop id="glass_city_background_vid2" style="opacity: 1" class="cover_img">
                <source src="https://www.midstory.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/paragraph2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <!-- Video Background 3 -->
            <video autoplay muted loop id="glass_city_background_vid3" style="opacity: 0" class="cover_img">
                <source src="https://www.midstory.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/paragraph3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <!-- Video Background 4 -->
            <video autoplay muted loop id="glass_city_background_vid4" style="opacity: 0" class="cover_img">
                <source src="https://www.midstory.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/end-quote.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any help / tips greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Set position to absolute to all video elements:

```
#sticky_top video {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```